# Laurent expansion of 1/sin(z)

Tags: laurent-series

I've been looking for a concise explanation of how to obtain the Laurent expansion for $$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$$
My attempt at it has me confused by it pretty quickly. I start with the knowledge that $$\sin(z)=z-\frac{1}{3!}z^3+\frac{1}{5!}z^5-...$$
Then I move that to the denominator to begin expanding the function at hand. I have gotten it to the form of a geometric series; namely,
$$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{3!}z^2-\frac{1}{5!}z^4+\cdots)}$$
I am unsure of how to proceed from here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the general term, or just the first few?

Comment: I would love to see how to obtain the first few. I'm using this to calculate a bunch of residues, so I do need it term-by-term. Thanks!! @Chappers

Comment: So for the first few terms, let $w = \frac{z^2}{3!} - \frac{z^4}{5!} + \dots$, then expand $\frac{1}{1-w}$ into a geometric series, and in $$\frac{1}{z}(1 + w + w^2 + \dotsc),$$ expand as many powers of $w$ as far as you need. For the residue, you need not go far at all.

Comment: You may use [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to evaluate $\dfrac z{z-z^3/3!+z^5/5!-z^7/7!}$.